# how mount (via terminal) ntfs external disk as non-root user

Tags: mount, ntfs, external-hdd

I can mount grafically ntfs usb disk as non-root (with Dolphin or Krusader), but I cannot mount in a terminal (/script) as user (non-root).
I read [these instructions](https://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#permissions) and I tried to follow them, but unsuccessfully: I get always an error message:

```
$ mount /media/duns/3giga
Error opening '/dev/sdc1': Permission denied
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Permission denied
Please check '/dev/sdc1' and the ntfs-3g binary permissions,
and the mounting user ID. More explanation is provided at
http://tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#unprivileged
```

It's possible or not mount via terminal a ntfs external disk as user non-root?
Thank you

Comment: `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdc1`

Comment: It works!!! Thank you!

Comment: But the problem is that I'm not sure that device will be always "/dev/sdc1": could I set something permanent?

Comment: use the disks UUID `/dev/disk/by-uuid/...` Get from `lsblk -o NAME,UUID /dev/sdc1`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!!

Comment: I think you could **answer** with this solution.

Comment: If you label your filesytems or (only with GPT) your partitions, you can also use `/dev/disk/by-label` or `/dev/disk/by-partlabel`.

Comment: @nobody Please provide an answer, avoid answering questions in comments.

Comment: @nobody Would you like to post an answer? If you do, ping me. I'll upvote :)